# firefox 86 completely ignoring sound settings

Tags: sound, firefox

Not sure what happened...but Firefox 86.0 on Ubuntu 20.10 is suddenly ignores ALL sound settings

1. Playback via internal speakers, even when everything else goes through headset
2. Ignoring system volume settings -- using function keys to increase/decrease sound has no effect.

All this stuff works in Chrome on the same system.

**UPDATE**:  I've noticed that if I disconnect the bluetooth headset, then FF at least respects the system volume settings.

Comment: Have you read your way through [this reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-to-do-if-firefox-wont-play-any-sounds)

Comment: @24601 - thanks for the lead.  No luck

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer....

1. Open the sound management app
2. Click the "hardware" tab
3. Choose the headphones device
4. Under profile, change it to something else.  (Mine was set to "A2DP Sink", I changed it to "HSP/HFP".  I could hear some scratch noise through the headphones.)
5. Change the setting back to "A2DP Sink"

Bingo!